# Set a default value in a select with simple array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple array:

```
items = ['All','item1','item2','item3'];
```

I have been tried

```
<select ng-model="ctrl.itemSelected" ng-change="ctrl.searchItem()">
    <option ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items" value="{{ctrl.items.indexOf(item)}}">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

However, my select is being rendered in the page as

```
<select ... >
    <option value='?' selected> </option>
    <option value='0'> All </option>
    <option value='1'> Item1 </option>
    <option value='2'> Item2 </option>
    <option value='3'> Item3 </option>
</select>
```

So I would like this were `<option value='0'> All </option>` my option selected at the beginning

What can I do?

Comment: declare your initialize value like these - data-ng-init="ctrl.itemSelected=0"  or from controller (js)

Comment: I tried it, but it was not enough. the first option with value="?" appears yet.

Comment: see here (https://plnkr.co/edit/I2MhSIx0ClL3XMLBSDFj?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do in your controller to initialize `itemSelected` model:

```
ctrl.itemSelected = items[0];
```

Comment: I tried it, but it's not work yet. The first option value="?" has been the initial element when I load the page.

Comment: @Kelyane It seems that's because of `value="{{ctrl.items.indexOf(item)}}"`. Just remove it and try, should work properly.

Comment: It works, but I also need the value as a number of my index array. Do you have any suggestion for it?

Comment: @Kelyane You can get it in the controller if it's acceptable for you, ex. `ctrl.items.indexOf(ctrl.itemSelected)`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<select ng-init="funcName= options[0]" ng-model="ctrl.itemSelected" ng-change="ctrl.searchItem()">
    <option ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items" value="{{ctrl.items.indexOf(item)}}">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the model which you've kept for your `select` needs to have an initial value. Since `ctrl.itemSelected` have no initial value, so your select option is set to a blank value at starting

Initialize your `select`'s model to a value from options. Like this

```
$scope.ctrl.itemSelected = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-selected` in `option`

```js
var app = angular.module('mapp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.items =  ['All','item1','item2','item3'];
   $scope.itemSelected = $scope.items[2];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="mapp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
{{itemSelected}}
  
<select ng-model="itemSelected">
    <option  ng-repeat="item in items" ng-selected="{{item == itemSelected}}" value="{{items.indexOf(item)}}">{{item}}</option>
</select>
  
</body>
```

Comment: I also tried it, but it didn't work. I mean the item with ng-selected=true is correct, but when I load the page the first element is the option with value="?", however when I click in another option, this first element no longer appears.

Comment: I update the code with your array, 
Where is the error getting for you ?

Answer (score 1):

array used as

```
$scope.items = ['All','item1','item2','item3'];

use the the Initialize the modal  
 ctrl.itemSelected = $scope.items[0];


<select ng-model="itemSelected">
    <option  ng-repeat="item in items" ng-selected="{{item == itemSelected}}" value="{{items.indexOf(item)}}">{{item}}</option>
</select>
```